# chrome desktop apps (extensions) won't launch at startup on mac osx

Tags: macos, google-chrome, login, google-chrome-extensions, node.js

I'm trying to figure out how to get a chrome desktop app ([Kiosk](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kiosk/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban?hl=en)) to launch at startup. I've gone to system preferences > accounts > login items and added Kiosk (User > Applications > Chrome Apps > Kiosk) but it won't launch.

Any idea how to get these to launch properly at startup on mac osx?

I do have an automator application running at startup which executes a few node.js commands from a bash script, so maybe I could do it that way, but I'm not sure how.

If I go to the application icon and get info, I can see it says:

`Default afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban.app` under name and extension, and its location is /Users/mikeheavers/Applications/Chrome Apps.localized but if I attempt to run:

`open -a Default /Users/mikeheavers/Applications/Chrome\ Apps.localized/afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban.app`

from terminal it says that the file doesn't exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It was a bit confusing so I'm posting the method I found here in case it's helpful to anyone.

- open `automator`
- got to `file > new` and select `application`
- from the library, choose `Run Shell Script` and drag it to the window
- In the run shell script dialog, enter the following:

`(/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban) &`

This launches the chrome kiosk app - you will need to get the app id for your specific chrome app by going to the application icon (located in `[user]/Applications/Chrome Apps/`), right clicking, and going to `get info`. The id will be listed after `Default` in `Name & Extension`.

- save the file somewhere, and then go to preferences > users and groups
- choose your user account, and go to login items
- click the `+` icon, and add the automator application you just created.
- restart, and your chrome app should launch as well.

Answer (score -1):

Default is part of the file name; you should be using the path `/Users/mikeheavers/Applications/Chrome\ Apps.localized/Default\ afhcomalholahplbjhnmahkoekoijban.app`